# How does a minimal DFA ensure minimal computational cost?

Tags: algorithms, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions, strings

I just went to read wikipedia to check a point on FA minimization, and
I read there the [following sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Minimum_DFA):

> The minimal DFA ensures minimal computational cost for tasks such as
>   pattern matching.

I have tried to imagine how, but my feeling is that DFA minimization
reduces the size of the program, which is especially important when it
is hardware, but will hardly do anything to speed up the computation
(well, indexing states might be easier when there are less states, depending
on computation model, but this seems far fetched).

Of course, from an abstract logical point of view, a minimal DFA does ensure
minimal computational cost, when that same cost is ensured by any DFA
for the language.

Am I missing a point? Which?

Comment: I think you're taking Wikipedia too literally. They probably mean that if you use DFA for implementation, then you might as well use the minimal one.

Comment: Note the smaller programs *can* execute fast (consider instruction caches) but that is probably not the point here. Since it's Wikipedia, my guess is that the author of that statement did not really know their stuff. (Also, you have to *construct* a DFA first, and *that* is expensive.)

Comment: I agree with @Raphael. Maybe the statement makes sense with NFA instead of DFA because fewer states can simplify the backtracking.

Comment: @babou If the automaton is deterministic no backtracking occurs so minimizing the automata will not reduce the computational cost of pattern matching. In other hand if you minimize a NFA you can have some reduction in computational cost although minimizing NFA is harder than minimizing a DFA.

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza Raphael's point was that a smaller program may execute faster, so that the smallest deterministic automaton may be faster, but I fear that non-determinism is usually a speed killer, whatever the size. There may be counter-examples, but ...

Comment: @babou I know that DFA tends to ensure less computational cost than NFA. I was just trying to make sense for your Wikipedia's sentence.